# simple user login validation module with node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm writing my first (non tutorial) node application and am at a point where I'm writing a function that should take the username and password as parameters and query them against the user table of my database to return either true or false. The database is setup, and the app is connecting to it successfully.

However, I haven't worked with SQL very much, nor node, and I'm unsure how to proceed with this function (and short surrounding script). Here it is:

```
console.log('validator module initialized');
var login = require("./db_connect");

function validate(username, password){

connection.connect();
console.log('Connection with the officeball MySQL database openned...');

connection.query(' //SQL query ', function(err, rows, fields) {
    //code to execute

});

connection.end();
console.log('...Connection with the officeball MySQL database closed.');


    if(){ //not exactly sure how this should be set up
        return true;
    }
    else{ //not exactly sure how this should be set up
        return false;
    }
}

exports.validate = validate;
```

This is using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). I'm looking for a basic example of how I might set the query and validation up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to rethink your app into a more node-like way (i.e. one that recognizes that many/most things happen asynchronously, so you're not usually "returning" from a function like this, but doing a callback from it. Not sure what you plan to get from node-mysql, but I would probably just use the plain mysql module. The following code is still most likely not entirely what you want, but will hopefully get you thinking about it correctly.

Note that the use of 'return' below is not actually returning a result (the callback itself should not return anything, and thus its like returning undefined. The return statements are there so you exit the function, which saves a lot of tedious if/else blocks.

Hope this helps, but I'd suggest looking at various node projects on github to get a better feel for the asynchronous nature of writing for node.

```
function validate(username, password, callback){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({ user:'foo',
                            password: 'bar',
                            database: 'test',
                            host:'127.0.0.1'});

    connection.connect(function (err){
        if (err) return callback(new Error('Failed to connect'), null);
        // if no error, you can do things now.

        connection.query('select username,password from usertable where username=?',
                username,
                function(err,rows,fields) {
                    //  we are done with the connection at this point), so can close it
                    connection.end();

                    // here is where you process results
                    if (err)
                        return callback(new Error ('Error while performing query'), null);
                    if (rows.length !== 1)
                        return callback(new Error ('Failed to find exactly one user'), null);

                    // test the password you provided against the one in the DB.
                    // note this is terrible practice - you should not store in the
                    // passwords in the clear, obviously. You should store a hash,
                    // but this is trying to get you on the right general path

                    if (rows[0].password === password) {
                        // you would probably want a more useful callback result than 
                        // just returning the username, but again - an example
                        return callback(null, rows[0].username);
                    } else {
                        return callback(new Error ('Bad Password'), null);
                    }

                });


    });
};
```

Comment: I started out with a mainly proceedural (OOP too) language, PHP, and the concept of non blocking code wan't there. It hasn't clicked yet but this is helping alot

Comment: Glad it helps. The non-blocking nature with its use of callbacks (and then some of the issues with how closures and variable access work when callbacks are involved) takes some getting used to, but after a while you just sort of pick up the idioms for it. There are also some libraries that help with issues of deeply nest callbacks. I illustrated this in [another node/mysql question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/) I answered this weekend.

Comment: You mentioned the 'plain mysql module', did you not mean this one? https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

Comment: when I search for using mysql with node, I've never found one built-in, and that module comes up each time.

However, now that I've updated my validator, the script complains that it can't find the "mysql" module when I require it. Tried moving the requirement to the index file of my script. Still can't find it. Tried reinstalling the module as well. A default module would be nice

Comment: Yes - sorry if I caused any confusion, that is correct. Its npm name is just mysql, so I thought you might have been talking about [this one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-mysql). To be clear the one you are using is the one I would recommend. Strange re the behavior you are describing. Did you do `npm install mysql` or did you try to install it just by downloading it from github?

Comment: I figured you meant that one. Have a look at this question? After adding your script (I'm sure it's my fault), my script hasn't been able to find the mysql module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132245/node-cant-find-installed-mysql-module

Comment: I included a brief console log, it shows the re-installation right before attempting to run the app. Must be an obvious beginner mistake that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: You just got my answer and another one on your other question, so you should be good to go. I am running out for a bit but will check the thread later in case you have further issues. Bon chance.