# How to use a for loop and get back results using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to run a script that does the same thing multiple times, but I don't want to get stuck writing callback after callback.   I am a bit of a beginner with node.js, so I am not sure the proper way of doing this.  Here is my code below:

```
exports.index = function (req,res) {
  /* some code */
  something.execute(this, that, function(results) {
    for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
      var nextPage = getNextPage(i);
    }
  }
}

function getNextPage(page) {
  something.execute(this, that, function(results) {
    return results;
  }
}
```

What happens is that result returns as undefined.  I know that this has to do something to do with that getNextPage is completed after the rest of the code because node is asynchronous, but I am unsure what the best way to approach this is.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

**Edit: Added code in getNextPage.  I am pretty much running the same code for 9 more pages.  It seems as though I need to figure out how to force the something.execute loop to run.**

Comment: Also, we can't say what's wrong until you show how you are assigning `result`.

Comment: you need to show more code or explain a bit more what your trying to do. if you suggest getNextPage() return undefined then you need to show the code for getNextPage()

Comment: It sounds like you know you can solve this problem by adding another callback, but you're reluctant to go there. A common pattern for combatting "too many nested callbacks" is to use any of several "Promises" libraries. https://github.com/kriskowal/q is one such. You might want to check it out. Promises add a bit of boilerplate to your async calls, but decouple them from your callbacks.

Comment: I agree with Jason's promises library suggestion as a general way to avoid the nested callback blues, which I think you will find otherwise unavoidable (nature of the node beast). If it is may be helpful, I provided an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/22110015#22110015) with a heavily-commented Q promises example yesterday as well as the equivalent non-promise version. More generally, the other commenters are correct that we'd need more code to provide any real help.

Comment: +1 for using promises for flow control.  Although for paged information using a stream would be my preferred approach.  https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream

Comment: I just looked up the Q library, but it is quite confusing to me.  I added some more code in my question, would it be the right tool?

Answer (score 1):

The best overview of the many ways/styles of coding this in node I think is [Mixu's Node Book Ch 7 "Control Flow"](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html). Specifically examples "7.2.1 Control flow pattern #1: Series - an asynchronous for loop" and "7.2.2 Control flow pattern #2: Full parallel - an asynchronous, parallel for loop". I pasted 7.2.1 here for you since many stackoverflow users frown upon external links without an excerpt.

```
function async(arg, callback) {
  console.log('do something with \''+arg+'\', return 1 sec later');
  setTimeout(function() { callback(arg * 2); }, 1000);
}
function final() { console.log('Done', results); }

var items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var results = [];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  async(item, function(result){
    results.push(result);
    if(results.length == items.length) {
      final();
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: This may work, but it's quite different semantically: it executes `forEach` items in parallel. Back to the OP's code, it would be a problem if the asynchronous `getNextPage` depends on the result of the previous call. The `async.forEach` from Async.js would be more appropriate, IMO. It executes items asynchronously, but sequentially.

Comment: Yes, indeed. My point is in order to write node programs, you have to know the entire topic. Thus the link to the book. There's only so many times I want to post an answer for folks hitting the async challenge of javascript for the first time. I personally would probably use `async.eachLimit` but the message I'm trying to send is this is a core thing you just have to understand.

Comment: I see. I'm really looking forward for across-the-board, production support for `yield` in JavaScript, both in Node and all major browsers. It would make asynchronous programming in JavaScript a breeze, same as it is with `async/await` in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) module. `async` provides a number of convenient asynchronous control flow functions. You'll have the skill and confidence to write your own, later. For now, though:

```
var async = require('async');

function requestHandler(req, res) {
    var itemNumbers = ... // might depend on req; might not

    function getItem(itemNumber, callback) {
        // ... asynchronous function which calls back with (err, result)
    }

    function withResults(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            // handle the error
        } else {
            // respond normally
        }
    }

    async.map(itemNumbers, async, withResults);
}
```

`async.map` will call `getItem` once per item in `itemNumbers`. If any invocation `getItem` calls back with an error, `async.map` will call `withResults` back with that error. Otherwise, `async.map` will call back with a `null` for `err` and an array of `getItem` callback results for `results`.