# Node-mysql not working properly... need debug ideas

Tags: mysql, node.js, debugging, socket.io

I am using node-mysql for the first time, and I have a program with no errors, no warnings, but is not working properly... Here is the code for the program, very simple:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database:  'nodetest',
  port: 8080
});

connection.connect();
var usr = "BLASHDASD"
var userId = usr;
var sql = 'UPDATE userlist SET user1= ' + connection.escape(userId) + ' WHERE id=1 ';
console.log(sql);

connection.query('sql', function(err, rows, fields) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("BLAHSDBKASD");
});

connection.end();
```

And here is the console output:

```
C:\wamp\www\nodePHP-master\js>node nodeTest.js
UPDATE userlist SET user1= 'BLASHDASD' WHERE id=1
```

But nothing is happening in my MySQL table... I even copied and pasted the UPDATE line above and just ran it as SQL code and it worked great...  Need some ideas of what is going on.  Thanks a bunch

**EDIT:**

Answered my own question... was listening on wrong port, so connection was failing.  Here is updated code for those interested/search in the future:

```
//TEST

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database:  'nodetest',
  port: 3306,
});

connection.connect(function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("connected");
    }
});
var usr = "BLASHDASD"
var userId = usr;
var sql = 'UPDATE userlist SET user1= ' + connection.escape(userId) + ' WHERE id=1 ';
console.log(sql);

connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
  console.log(err);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: Please see my answer below. If your code works as it is written, you are just getting very lucky with timing. Try it against a remote database with a 'select' query and see if you have any results to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problems with node's asynchronous nature, a very common issue when coming to Node. You also had a small but significant error in your code (you have `'sql'` as a quoted string), but here is something structurally similar that should point you in the right direction.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'locahost',
    user     : 'foo',
    password : 'bar',
    database : 'test'
});

// the callback inside connect is called when the connection is good
connection.connect(function(err){
    var sql = "select 'Joe' as name from dual";

    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        //  you need to end your connection inside here.
        connection.end();
        console.log(rows[0].name);
    });
});
```

You will likely start wondering about ways to avoid all these callbacks. You may wish to look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/22110015#22110015) for a more extended mysql example as well as an alternative implementation which offers an alternative to callback-mania.

Comment: Caught the 'sql' error thanks!  Figured out but read through your post and the question you linked too... Appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd be curious to hear from the person who downvoted as to the reason??

Comment: @barry-johnson I liked your answer. I am gonna upvote it to make it up for you! :D

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti LOL - thanks, you're a prince! Although I have to say this is a very dated answer (although true as far as it goes). The linked question that discussed the promise-based implementation aged less well, as I would tend to recommend Bluebird or very often just native promises over Q.

Comment: @barry-johnson Even if dated, the answer would work even now! and looks good to me! There was no need for a downvote! I don't what was the person thinking :D That's why i chose to upvote :D