# How to connect html document to sql database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

So I am trying to connect my SQL database to an HTML file for my website. I have heard that you can use Node.js to do this, but I am not sure how to add node.js to my HTML and also connect it to my other JavaScript so I can record things from there.

Comment: This question seems duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387459/how-to-use-sql-with-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install nodejs first.refer this:https://nodejs.org/en/download/
then you need to install mysql using : `npm install mysql`
then configure mysql using :

```
  const mysql = require('mysql');
  var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host           : "localhost",
    user           : "username",
    password       : "password",
    database       : "databasename"
});
```