# node-mysql how to use result outside of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I have a query like below:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `Id` = ?;', [Id], function (err, row) {
var a = row;
});

//how can I use variable `a` in here?
```

Comment: This is basic javascript, I would highly recommend reading a basic tutorial on javascript and callbacks

Comment: You'll need to move the stuff after connection.query() into the callback or, perhaps better, call a function and pass the row variable to it.

Comment: You should understand that even thought in your example callback is defined inline you can pass as well function name, it's not that the results of query are inside query, they are passed to function and it can be defined elsewhere (but in accessible scope)

Answer (score 0):

you really won't be able to. at least not easily.

```
var a;
connection.query('SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `Id` = ?;', [Id], function (err, row) {
    a = row;
});
//execute stuff
```

This will accomplish getting the value out into the next scope but where you would `//execute stuff` will have already happened before a is set. This is because (I'm assuming) node-mysql is asynchronous.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption as well as your general answer. The OP might find [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/22110015#22110015) which I answered helpful. It provides two approaches (callbacks and promises) for using mysql asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you for a assurance, I didn't delve into using callbacks as OP strictly wanted to use a after the call, but thank you for your link.

Comment: Understand entirely. My suspicion is he most likely is somewhat new to node and might not realize he'll probably need to do what he wants inside the callback (for the reason you identified) or come up with a different approach to deferring execution until having the data he wants available.