# Why does queryAsync() result in added meta data?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, metadata

I used `queryAsync()` as prescribed by an answer to a question, and it works, but it adds lots of extra meta data to my query result, which is otherwise a straightforward query.

---

Here's what I'm using to process/execute the query and log the result:

```
var retrieveSettings = Promise.method(function (username, connection) {
    console.log('User ' + username + ' retrieving settings...');
    var q = 'select * from sales_settings';
    return connection.queryAsync(q).then(function (rows, fields) {
        list = [];
        for (x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
            list.push(rows[x]);
        }
        //console.log('Settings: ' + JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
        return list;
    });
});
```

and here is the result that is logged:

```
Settings: [
    [
        {
            "group_name": "add_auto",
            "commission_rate": 0,
            "monthly_req": 0,
            "category_name": "Auto",
            "commission_type": "none",
            "group_title": "Added Auto"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "add_fire",
            "commission_rate": 0,
            "monthly_req": 0,
            "category_name": "Fire",
            "commission_type": "none",
            "group_title": "Added Fire"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "bank_dep",
            "commission_rate": 25,
            "monthly_req": 0,
            "category_name": "Bank",
            "commission_type": "static",
            "group_title": "Bank Deposit"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "bank_loan",
            "commission_rate": 75,
            "monthly_req": 8,
            "category_name": "Bank",
            "commission_type": "static",
            "group_title": "Bank Loan"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "health",
            "commission_rate": 0.084,
            "monthly_req": 4,
            "category_name": "Health",
            "commission_type": "premium",
            "group_title": "Health App"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "life",
            "commission_rate": 0.084,
            "monthly_req": 8,
            "category_name": "Life",
            "commission_type": "premium",
            "group_title": "Life App"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "new_auto",
            "commission_rate": 0.03,
            "monthly_req": 32,
            "category_name": "Auto",
            "commission_type": "rate",
            "group_title": "Raw New Auto"
        },
        {
            "group_name": "new_fire",
            "commission_rate": 0.03,
            "monthly_req": 20,
            "category_name": "Fire",
            "commission_type": "rate",
            "group_title": "Raw New Fire"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "group_name",
            "orgName": "group_name",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 33,
            "length": 135,
            "type": 253,
            "flags": 20483,
            "decimals": 0,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        },
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "commission_rate",
            "orgName": "commission_rate",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 63,
            "length": 13,
            "type": 246,
            "flags": 4097,
            "decimals": 3,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        },
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "monthly_req",
            "orgName": "monthly_req",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 63,
            "length": 11,
            "type": 3,
            "flags": 4097,
            "decimals": 0,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        },
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "category_name",
            "orgName": "category_name",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 33,
            "length": 135,
            "type": 253,
            "flags": 4097,
            "decimals": 0,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        },
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "commission_type",
            "orgName": "commission_type",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 33,
            "length": 135,
            "type": 253,
            "flags": 4097,
            "decimals": 0,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        },
        {
            "catalog": "def",
            "db": "officeball",
            "table": "sales_settings",
            "orgTable": "sales_settings",
            "name": "group_title",
            "orgName": "group_title",
            "filler1": [
                12
            ],
            "charsetNr": 33,
            "length": 72,
            "type": 253,
            "flags": 4097,
            "decimals": 0,
            "filler2": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "zeroFill": false,
            "protocol41": true
        }
    ]
]
```

---

Why is this unusual meta data being added to my query result?

Comment: I'm assuming that `queryAsync()` is a built-in method of the Node-MySQL connection object. If not, I'm not sure which api it comes from, either q or bluebird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard callback from mysql's `query()` returns both a `rows` and `fields`. The asynch wrapper you are using (for example if you `Q.denodeify()`) is only returning a single thing, so for callbacks with multiple parameters it returns an array of `[param1,param2]` in this case `[rows,fields]`.

Related to this, your function inside the `then` needs to accept only one parameter (which would be this array of [rows,fields]).

See the second portion of my answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109487/nodejs-mysql-dump/22110015#22110015) as an illustration.

Your code should thus be something like:

```
var retrieveSettings = Promise.method(function (username, connection) {
    console.log('User ' + username + ' retrieving settings...');
    var q = 'select * from sales_settings';
    return connection.queryAsync(q).then(function (results) {
        var rows = results[0]; // get the rows
        var fields = results[1]; // don't really care, but just for illustration
        list = [];
        for (x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
            list.push(rows[x]);
        }
        //console.log('Settings: ' + JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
        return list;
    });
});
```

And actually, for the above code, there's no reason your entire callback can't just be:

```
    return connection.queryAsync(q).then(function (results) {
        return results[0]; // get the rows
    });
```

Comment: You bet. Good move adopting a promises approach on the asynchronous stuff, once you get used to another set of idioms & idiosyncrasies, I think it makes for some much more readable code - this multi-param handling issue is one of the few places where it makes for slightly uglier code. IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using bluebird, in that case you can use `.spread`:

```
var retrieveSettings = Promise.method(function (username, connection) {
    console.log('User ' + username + ' retrieving settings...');
    var q = 'select * from sales_settings';
    return connection.queryAsync(q).spread(function (rows, fields) {
        list = [];
        for (x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {
            list.push(rows[x]);
        }
        //console.log('Settings: ' + JSON.stringify(list, null, 4));
        return list;
    });
});
```

The problem with the mysql module is that it doesn't conform to the node js callback standard which is `(err, result)`. Instead it uses `(err, result1, result2)`. Because functions can only throw one exception or return one value, bluebird returns an array of `[result1, result2]` to avoid information loss.

`.spread` is like `.then` except it assumes the fulfulliment value is an array and spreads the array's values over the arguments.